# Web Bluetooth characteristic characteristicvaluechanged on mobile

Tags: google-chrome, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, web-bluetooth

I need to read out values from multiple characteristics from a BLE device with Web Bluetooth. This all works fine on my Mac OSX Chrome but I'm only getting one notification on my mobile's Chrome (One+ 6T running Android 9). It connects to the device, finds the characteristics but it only receives the first value change and then that's it.

Any ideas/helps would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You may need to set the MTU for Android devices. I am an Android developer not a web dev but try setting the MTU to 512.

Comment: @temp_ I'd love to try that but I can't seem to find a WebBluetooth API to request an MTU change...

Comment: Can you include a sample of the code you've written?